# Join 2 Alias Table from Union Select Table with same numbers of row

Tags: postgresql

I hava 2 table from alias table result of select and union with have same number of row, how or can i make table 2 in right side of table 1? There are dont have same record
Thank you

First query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) “DATA 220” FROM istros_sls_store.sales_store_220)—CEK
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM istros_sls_item_sales_item_220)—CEK
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM istros_sls_scat_sales_small_cat_220—CEK
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM istros_inventory_hstr.inventory_hstr_dtl_220)—CEK
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM istros_sos.stock_out_supplier_220—CEK
) a
```

Output from first query:

```
DATA 220
41
236633
11509
187174
1132
```

Second query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) “DATA 226” FROM istros_sls_store.sales_store_226—CEK
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM istros_sls_item_sales_item_226—CEK
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM istros_sls_scat_sales_small_cat_226—CEK
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM istros_inventory_hstr.inventory_hstr_dtl_226—CEK
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM istros_sos.stock_out_supplier_226—CEK
) b
```

Output from second query:

```
DATA 226
41
243053
11437
193549
960
```

The desired output combines these two columns:

```
DATA 220 | DATA 226
41       | 41
236633   | 243053
11509    | 11437
187174   | 193549
1132     | 960
```

Comment: Please do not include images, but rather _text_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try simple selecting both counts in the union query, so that each one appears as a separate column in the output.  Note that below I introduce a computed column, `pos`, which keeps track of which count queries should appear first in the result set.

```
SELECT "DATA 220", "DATA 226"
FROM
(
    SELECT
        1 AS pos,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM istros_sls_store.sales_store_220) AS “DATA 220”,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM istros_sls_store.sales_store_226) AS “DATA 226”
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        2,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM istros_sls_item_sales_item_220),
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM istros_sls_item_sales_item_226)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        3,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM istros_sls_scat_sales_small_cat_220),
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM istros_sls_scat_sales_small_cat_226)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        4,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM istros_inventory_hstr.inventory_hstr_dtl_220),
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM istros_inventory_hstr.inventory_hstr_dtl_226)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        5,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM istros_sos.stock_out_supplier_220),
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM istros_sos.stock_out_supplier_226)
) t
ORDER BY
    pos;
```

Comment: Oke Thank you Mr. Biegeleisen, i try it and succes :) . And thanks to for the suggestion, gbu (y)